# AngularJS $q service response in sequence with exception handling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, promise, q

I have a function which gives me response in sequence for asynchronous call using promises for a `for` loop but loop breaks when i got a exception from code, but i want to continue my loop even after a exception throw from function.

my async function is

```
function asyncFun(a) { 
    var q = $q.defer(); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(a == 4) throw new Error('custom error'); 
        q.resolve(a);
    }, 1000); 
    return q.promise; 
}
```

and chain function is

```
function getData() {
    var chain = $q.when();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            chain = chain.then(function() {
                return asyncFun(i).then(function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                }).catch(function(ex) {
                    throw ex;
                });
            }).catch(function(ex) { throw ex });
        })(i);
    };
    return chain
}
```

and when i call `getData();` it stop the loop after throw error on `i = 4` but i want to continue the `for` loop for all 10 entry.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How will you hangle the error? There is no way that one of your promise is rejected while you're continuing to perform the loop. Maybe you should treat that error as a special value and resolve it as you resolve normal value.

Comment: My `asyncFun` is predefined with throw error in some condition, that why i need changes in `getData` for completing the loop.

Comment: why did vote down this question without understanding the problem

Comment: I did not vote down this question. Maybe it's another guy...

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment, the errors may be treated as special values so you can perform special behaviours after the chain promises.

Try this code:

```
function getData() {
    var chain = $q.when();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            chain = chain.then(function() {
                return asyncFun(i).then(function(res) {
                    console.log(res)
                }).catch(function(ex) {
                    console.log(ex); // do not throw error but handle the error
                });
            }).catch(function(ex) { throw ex });
        })(i);
    };
    return chain
}
```